# Line of intersection between two planes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

The questions asks: Determine the line of intersection in vector, parametric, and Cartesian between the following sets of planes:

$2x-y+2z+1=0$ and $-4x+2y-4z-2=0$

I realize these are parallel to one another, but have no clue how to get the point and then convert to the various forms. Please help

Answer (score 1):

HINT: multiplying the first plane by $-2$ we get the same plane, these two planes are the same

Comment: right so I was half-right, they are the same plane. But based on this, how can I possibly find a point of intersection?

Comment: the solutions are the points satisfying the equation $$2x-y+2z+1=0$$

Comment: I got the answer, but can you explain the concept? Two planes which are actually just one as they are multiples of one another. If I only solve for one plane, how can there be a point of intersection when nothing is intersecting it?

Comment: the intersecting are two planes which are identical

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui Think of the intersection like this: You investigate all points of space. When a point satisfy the two equations at the same time, put down a mark. If you do this you will eventually have marked the plane(s), which is identical to the intersection.

Comment: From here, can I just convert the cartesian equation of one of the planes to their vector and parametric form? @Lovsovs

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui Yes.